# GetPrinterDriverDirectory set 1780 errorcode

Tags: winapi, printing

Please, explain me what means 1780 RPC_X_NULL_REF_POINTER - "A null reference pointer was passed to the stub."
There is some code/ where I am calling GetPrinterDriverDirectory():

```
char DriverDir[MAX_PATH];
LPDWORD needed = 0;
Result = GetPrinterDriverDirectory(NULL, TEXT("Windows x86"), 1, (LPBYTE)&DriverDir, MAX_PATH, needed);
```

P.S. Spooler and RPC services are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter should be a pointer to a `DWORD` rather than `0`. This should work:

```
DWORD needed = 0;
Result = GetPrinterDriverDirectory(NULL, TEXT("Windows x86"), 1, (LPBYTE)&DriverDir, MAX_PATH, &needed);
```